# Laravel 9 unable to connect with AWS S3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-9

I am trying to store some images from a Laravel API in an S3 bucket but noting is working

I have configured my project accordingly

.env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*************
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=**********************
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=me-south-1
AWS_BUCKET=bucket-name
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
```

filesystems.php

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],
```

installed the Flysystem S3 package using
`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0"`

running lines such as `$request->file('filename')->storeAs($directory, $imgName, 's3');`
causes no errors but doesn't upload anything to the s3 bucket either.

To test basic connection I manually uploaded an `image.png` file to the s3 bucket and tried something like this.

```
if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists('image.png')){
            echo "exists";
        }else{
            echo "connection issue";
        }
```

but it caused the following error

```
  "message": "Unable to check existence for: image.png",
    "exception": "League\\Flysystem\\UnableToCheckDirectoryExistence",
```

Moreover, the AWS IAM dashboard states that the access key used in the .env file has never been used before.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have access to the actual exception from S3?

Comment: Does this need a "/" infront of the image.png. This occured for me once trying to check top level images in a bucket.

Comment: @Victor, I am not sure where I can find this and I do not think any exception will exist as the AWS environment seems to be untouched by my Laravel app. But if you can point me on where to find it I can share it

Comment: @Ashler2, I tried again with / in front of image.png. Nothing different

Comment: @AsemIbrahim I know nothing about Laravel, but I see a parameter `throw` in your code snippet set to `false`. Can you set it to true instead maybe?

Comment: I just did, nothing changed in the way it displays the errors and no S3 logs were created

Comment: As you know the file exists, are you able to get the file to make sure its not just an issue with that function? I've found the following - https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/1630

Comment: In `php artisan tinker`, do `config('filesystems.disks.s3')` to ensure your keys are correctly set. (It's possible you've got a cached config.) Barring that, check your IAM permissions. There's a half dozen or so you'll need, not just `GetObject`.

Comment: I have exahusted all your suggestions, nothing still works. I have shifted to hosting the entire webapp on an EC2 instance and swapped accessing the S3 bucket with the access keys to accessing it with IAM roles, which ended up working

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still struggling with this, I ended up giving up on trying to access the S3 bucket through access keys and instead opted for hosting the webapp on an EC2 instance and accessing the bucket through IAM Roles.

1. **Create and verify an IAM role for your EC2 instance**

On this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/).

2. **Configure Laravel as follows**

> .env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=your-bucket-region
AWS_BUCKET=your-bucket-name
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=true
```

> filesystem.php

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
    'throw' => false,
],
```